# mathpazo, mathdesign and kpfonts

Tags: fonts, mathpazo, mathdesign, kpfonts

is possible have the `\usepackage{mathpazo}` with `\usepackage[nomath,fulloldstylenums,fulloldstyle]{kpfonts}` but with the integrals symbols (`\int \oint` ecc) from the `\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}` and the `\ell` character from the `\usepackage[fulloldstylenums,fulloldstyle]{kpfonts}` ?

[image]

### for me, the serifs of the `\int` from `\usepackage{mathpazo}` is not according to the kpfonts; or i'm wrong?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}

\usepackage[nomath,fulloldstylenums,fulloldstyle]{kpfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\int f(x)\, dx
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this does everything that you want. The basic idea is to take individual symbols from `mathdesign` and `kpfonts`. Most of the code comes from [mdput.sty](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathdesign), which is part of `mathdesign`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[nomath,fulloldstylenums,fulloldstyle]{kpfonts}

\makeatletter
\def\MD@def#1#2{\global\let#2=\@undefined #1#2}

\DeclareSymbolFont{md}{OMX}{mdput}{m}{n}%   
\MD@def\DeclareMathSymbol{\oint}{\mathop}{md}{72}
\MD@def\DeclareMathSymbol{\int}{\mathop}{md}{90}

\DeclareFontEncoding{MDB}{}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathdesignB}{MDB}{mdput}{m}{n}% 

\MD@def\DeclareMathSymbol{\intclockwise}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{128}
\MD@def\DeclareMathSymbol{\ointclockwise}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{130}
\MD@def\DeclareMathSymbol{\ointctrclockwise}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{132}
\MD@def\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiint}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{134}
\MD@def\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiiint}{\mathop}{mathdesignB}{136}

\DeclareSymbolFont{kpletters}{OML}{jkpss}{m}{it}
\MD@def\DeclareMathSymbol{\ell}{\mathchar}{kpletters}{96}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. $\ell$
\begin{equation}
\ointctrclockwise \ointclockwise \intclockwise \oint \int \oiint \oiiint f(x)\, dx
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```