# Borrowing \varg from pxfonts.sty

Tags: mathpazo

I preferentially use [mathpazo.sty](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathpazo) for writing scientific papers and appendix.

I'm borrowing `\ell` from kpfonst.sty, following [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66707/mathpazo-mathdesign-and-kpfonts), because `\ell` in `mathpazo.sty` is a bit less fitted with other symbols with mathpazo.

Question: how can I borrow `\varg` from `pxfonts.sty` to use it with `mathpazo.sty`?

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathpazo}

\DeclareSymbolFont{pxlettersA}{U}{pxmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{pxlettersA}{bold}{U}{pxmia}{bx}{it}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\varg}{\mathord}{pxlettersA}{49}

\begin{document}

$g \varg$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion as well as the general method (my apology for the duplication though!).